# CheckBox caption position in FormLayout (Vaadin 7.5.0)

Tags: vaadin7

I have a problem with the `FormLayout` and the CheckBox component. I want to use the `FormLayout` to generate  a form for the user. This means I want to have all options in the form (`Textinput, Numberinput, Options...`) aligned by the `Formlayout` with the `caption` to the `left` and the `input` to the right.

This works well with other components but not with `CheckBox`. It always places its caption to the right of the Box, which breaks the visual order of my form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Vaadin, the implementation of a component can decide if it renders its caption by itself or if its parent, a component container, renders it. Most of the components let the parent to render the caption. `CheckBox` is a component that renders its caption by itself.

To fix the problem, you could wrap your `CheckBox` inside a layout (`CssLayout` for example) and set the caption for the layout, or you could use this addon: [FormCheckBox](https://vaadin.com/addon/formcheckbox).